# Scikit - How to get single term for similar words using sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tf-idf

I'm new to text analysis and scikit-learn. I am trying to vectorize tweets using sklearn's *TfidfVectorizer* class. When I listed the terms using 'get_feature_names()' after vactorizing the tweets, I see similar words such as '*goal*', '*gooooal*' or '*goaaaaaal*' as different terms.

Question is, How can I make a single term 'goal' for such similar but different words using sklearn feature extraction techniques (or any other techniques) to get my results better?

Answer (score 2):

In short - you can't. This is a very complex problem, going to the whole language understanding. Think for a moment - can you define exactly what does it mean to be "similar but different"? If you can't, computer will not be able to, too. What you can do?

1. You can come up with easy preprocessing rules, such as "remove any repeating letters", which will fix the "goal" problem. (this should not lead to any further problems)
2. You can use existing databases of synonyms (like wordnet) to "merge" the same meaning to the same tokens (this might cause false positive - you might "merge" words of different meaning due to the lack of context analysis)
3. You can build some language model and use it to embed your data in a lower-dimensional space forcing your model to merge similar meanings (using the well known heuristics "words that occur in similar contexts have similar meaning"). One of such technique is [Latent Semantic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) but obviously there are many more possible.